# Python - Open/Switch tab in Selenium + Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver

Open new tab -

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

Switch back to first tab -

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.ALT + Keys.NUMPAD1)
```

The above lines work perfectly in `Firefox webdriver` but fails in `Chrome webdriver`.

Comment: what's the chromedriver & selenium version?

Comment: selenium 2.40.0 and chromedriver 2.9 - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: Is the chrome version 34? Coz their is some issue with chrome 34 version https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=772